# What does the spaCy PhraseMatcher match on?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

What attributes of the tokens within a `doc` object does a `PhraseMatcher` check for and require to find a match?

For example, if I just create a `doc` using

```
doc1 = nlp('lead')
```

then the 'lead' token is an ADJ, whereas if I have a doc such as

```
doc2 = nlp('lead plate')
```

then the 'lead' token is a NOUN.

If I add `doc1` to a `PhraseMatcher` instance, should I expect that this matcher finds a match in `doc2`?

Similarly for if I have, e.g.

```
doc1 = nlp('Lead')
doc2 = nlp('lead')
```

I.e. is it case sensitive?

This is not to mention token attributes like dependency, etc. I didn't find the documentation to be clear on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PhraseMatcher` will match on the `ORTH` value, i.e. the exact text. This lets it match large terminology lists and exact occurrences of strings, without having to worry about spaCy's tokenization. For more background on this, why the `PhraseMatcher` can't work on other attributes, and possible solutions for case-insensitivity, see [this discussion on the issue tracker](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1579).

If you want to match based on token attributes, you'll probably want to use the rule-based `Matcher` instead:

```
pattern = [{"LOWER": "lead", "POS": "ADJ"}]
```

There's also this [newly added example](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#regex) in the docs that shows how to use the `Matcher` with token match patterns and regular expressions (or binary flags more generally). This can be useful to add your own custom token descriptions like different spellings.

You might also want to check out [`spacy-lookup`](https://github.com/mpuig/spacy-lookup), a community plugin that uses the FlashText module and provides an alternative to the built-in `PhraseMatcher`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you (and thanks for developing spaCy)!